# DirectFB bringup

Tags: fedora, directfb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop a DirectFB app without leaving X.11 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521957/how-to-develop-a-directfb-app-without-leaving-x-11-environment)

I installed DirectFB 1.4.3 in my Fedora PC. When I try to run some bin application of DirectFB like "dfbinfo", I get the following error:

"opening /dev/fb0 failed. No such file or directory. Error opening framebuffer device!"

I checked in framebuffer is enabled in kernel by verifying /boot/config file and its enabled.

Can someone let me know how to enable the framebuffer device /dev/fb0?

Comment: I believe this was already discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521957/how-to-develop-a-directfb-app-without-leaving-x-11-environment

Answer (score 0):

Opening /dev/fd0 with "No such file or directory" error could be due to lack of framebuffer kernel module.
This is one with a name like xxxxxfb.ko
The path for this module is /lib/modules/YOUR_KERNEL
Try to find all of them:

$find /lib/modules/YOUR_KERNEL | grep fb.ko

Then figure out what is the appropriate one for your system and load it with

$insmod ....

Then try:

$sudo cat /dev/fb0

If successful, you will see a lot of output.
Then your test should also work.