# Development and testing of framebuffer apps without leaving X11

Tags: linux, user-interface, x11, framebuffer

I am developing an embedded application that will run on the framebuffer on the target device. Is it possible to develop and test such an application on a development machine (a standard desktop PC) without leaving X11?

I know there is a [virtual framebuffer for Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvfb.html). I am looking to something similar to this, but not Qt-specific.

Note: This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521957/how-to-develop-a-directfb-app-without-leaving-x-11-environment), but not related to DirectFB.

Comment: A virtual machine should work

Comment: Yes, and running on the target via nfs works too, but I'm looking for a way to speed up the development / testing cycle... Isn't there a way to run a fb application on X11?

Comment: "Without leaving X11".

Comment: If you come up and go to the kitchen to have a cup of coffee, is this "leaving X11"? Looking at another console is neither.